# Changed Display Name of XCode Project, now getting error

Tags: ios, xcode

I changed the name of my Display Name in Xcode in the General tab(Don't do this), and now it will not build to my iPhone. It will build to the simulator, though. I changed the name from Project1 to Project 2: Build -> Failed. I changed it back to Project1 -> Build failed. It will not work now.

Here is the error:

> error: /Users/treyw./Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Score_Keeper-ffykvkyyltqhhlfkdvjvrdbhsywn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Score Keeper.build/Debug-iphoneos/Score Keeper.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Score_Keeper.swiftmodule: No such file or directory (in target 'Score Keeper' from project 'Score Keeper')

I have found a few posts saying to go to Build Phases-> Copy Bundle Resources -> And delete whatever is red. I've deleted everything in there and it doesn't help. I have also seen a post where someone says if there are spaces in your folder, I need to change them to no spaces. But I cannot find these folders anywhere in Finder. I can go to /Users/treyw./ but there is no Library to keep going. Of course, the error is no such file or directory, but I don't even know where this error is referring to start with this one. Thank you in advance!

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r56RV.png)

Comment: Did you try to delete the Derived Data directory. You see the path in the error message or go to the menu entry Product -> Show Derived Data Folder. After that try to rebuild. It should fix it

Comment: Thank you so much, it appears Xcode is setup a bit different for this specific location than what you suggested. I was eventually able to find the folder, though. It was Product -> Show Build Folder in Finder -> Then I had to backtrack a few folders in the directory to find the Derived Data Folder. The folder with the ffykvkyyltqhhlfkdvjvrdbhsywn as shown in the error is the folder I deleted and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In the Info.Plist change the following

"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Name of the app";
"CFBundleName"  = "Name of the app";